# Updatepanel and jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jqgrid

can update panel and jqgrid work together?
i am using jqgrid and i want to control page refreshing. so i added update panel but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

UpdatePanels are supported. You can use our Master -> Detail example online that embeds to jqGrid instances inside UpdatePanel as a starting point:
[MasterDetail jqgrid inside an update panel](http://www.trirand.net/examples/selection/masterdetail/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstantiate your jqgrid after partial postback like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    //Calls the function to load the for the first time
                    LoadGrid();
                    **var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
                    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
                    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
                    }
                    // fires after the partial update of UpdatePanel
                    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
                        //Calls the function again to load the grid after  partial postback
                        LoadGrid();
                    }**

                    function LoadGrid() {
                        jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                            url: '/GridHandler.ashx',
                            datatype: "json",
                            colNames: ['Id', 'Village Name', 'Village Area'],
                            colModel: [
                            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 30, sorttype: 'int', sortable: true },
                            { name: 'VillageName', index: 'VillageName', width: 170, sorttype: 'text', sortable: true },
                            {
                                name: 'VillageArea', index: 'VillageArea', width: 70, align: "right", sorttype: 'int',
                                sortable: true, formatter: 'integer', formatoptions: { thousandsSeparator: "," }
                            },
                            ],
                            //pager: "#pager",
                            rowNum: 1000,
                            height: 441,
                            width: 288,
                            loadonce: true,
                            sortname: 'Id',
                            viewrecords: true,
                            sortorder: "asc",
                            caption: "List of Villages",
                            shrinkToFit: 'false',
                            onSelectRow: function () {
                                //Gets the Id of selected row
                                var sel_id = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                var selectedVillage = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'VillageName');

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    async: false,
                                    url: "HomeModified.aspx/GridRowSelect",
                                    data: "{'village':'" + selectedVillage + "'}",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        GenerateMap();

                                    },
                                    error: function (result) {
                                        alert("There is an error in generating map");
                                    }
                                });

                                function GenerateMap() {
                                    document.getElementById("<%=hiddenButton.ClientID %>").click();
                                $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '/GridHandler.ashx', datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }]);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    }



                </script>
```